# Function.bind used in event binding will always re-render because it is not pure

Tags: performance, reactjs

Working on render performance on React, wonder what is the best way to tackle this performance issue. (The code is overly simplified for clarity)

```
var TodoList = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return { todos: Immutable.List(['Buy milk', 'Buy eggs']) };
    },
    onTodoChange: function (index, newValue) {
        this.setState({
            todos: this.state.todos.set(index, newValue)
        });
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            this.state.todos.map((todo, index) =>
                <TodoItem
                    value={todo}
                    onChange={this.onTodoChange.bind(null, index)} />
            )
        );
    }
});
```

Assume only one single todo item has been changed. First, `TodoList.render()` will be called and start re-render the list again. Since `TodoItem.onChange` is binding to a event handler thru `bind`, thus, `TodoItem.onChange` will have a new value every time `TodoList.render()` is called. That means, even though we applied `React.addons.PureRenderMixin` to `TodoItem.mixins`, not one but all `TodoItem` will be re-rendered even when their `value` has not been changed.

I believe there are multiple ways to solve this, I am looking for an elegant way to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When looping through UI components in React, you need to use the `key` property. This allows for like-for-like comparisons. You will probably have seen the following warning in the console.

> Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.

It's tempting to use the `index` property as the key, and if the list is static this may be a good choice (if only to get rid of the warning). However if the list is dynamic, you need a better key. In this case, I'd opt for the value of the todo item itself.

```
render: function () {
    return (
        this.state.todos.map((todo, index) => (
            <TodoItem
                key={todo}
                value={todo}
                onChange={this.onTodoChange.bind(null, index)}
            />
        ))
    );
}
```

Finally, I think your conjecture about the nature of the `onChange` property is off the mark. Yes it will be a different property each time it is rendered. But the property itself has no rendering effect, so it doesn't come into play in the virtual DOM comparison.

**UPDATE**

(This answer has been updated based on the conversation below.)

Whilst it's true that a change to a non-render based prop like `onChange` won't trigger a re-render, it will trigger a virtual DOM comparison. Depending on the size of your app, this may be expensive or it may be trivial.

Should it be necessary to avoid this comparison, you'll need to implement the component's `shouldComponentUpdate` method to ignore any changes to non-render based props. e.g.

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {

    const ignoreProps = [ 'onChange' ];

    const keys = Object.keys(this.props)
        .filter((k) => ignoreProps.indexOf(k) === -1);

    const keysNext = Object.keys(nextProps)
        .filter((k) => ignoreProps.indexOf(k) === -1);

    return keysNext.length !== keys.length ||
        keysNext.some((k) => nextProps[k] !== this.props[k]);

}
```

If using state, you'll also need to compare `nextState` to `this.state`.

Comment: I over-simplified the code to omit the "key" for clarity. Even though "key" is added, the "onChange" is still a new instance every time `render` is called.

In our real world scenario, our `TodoItem` is complicated. Therefore, we are seeing 20-30 ms for every `TodoItem.render`. Even though it is not rendered to browser DOM, the virtual DOM performance impact is still not negligible.

Comment: OK I see now. In that case, you probably want to roll your own `shouldComponentUpdate` in `TodoItem` to compare every prop except onChange.

Comment: Okay, let's assume I return `false` on `shouldComponentUpdate` for `onChange`. If `onChange` handler really need to be updated, will this break?

Comment: No, I don't believe so. The prop will still be received, it just won't trigger a re-render.

Comment: Tested, you are right. Even `shouldComponentUpdate` return `false`, `this.props` will be updated with `nextProps`.

That means we should implement `shouldComponentUpdate` that ignore changes for `/^on[A-Z]/`.

Could you please update your answer?

Comment: Done. Code and explanation inserted for anyone else that may come across this.